# c - Fuga de memoria en realloc

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

llevo dos días con una fuga de memoria en un realloc y no encuentro el problema.

Aquí os adjunto el código:

```html
#include "palabra.h"

Palabra * palabraNueva(){
 Palabra* pal = NULL;

 pal = (Palabra*)malloc(sizeof(Palabra));

 if(pal == NULL){
  printf("Error en la reserva de la palabra\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 pal->tamano = 0;

 pal->contenido = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*pal->tamano);
 if(pal->contenido == NULL){
  printf("Error al reservar memoria a la coleccion de letras\n");
 }

 return pal;
}


void palabraElimina(Palabra * p_p){

    int i;

 if(p_p->tamano != 0 ){
    for(i=0 ; i < p_p->tamano; i++){
        free(p_p->contenido[i]);
    }
 free(p_p->contenido);
 }
    free(p_p);
}

Palabra * palabraInsertaLetra(Palabra * p_p, char * letra){

 int longitud;
 int tam = 0;

 if(letra == NULL){
  printf("Letra vacia, Error\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 longitud = p_p->tamano;

 tam = strlen(letra) + 1;

 p_p->contenido=(char**)realloc(p_p->contenido,sizeof(char*)*(longitud+1));

 p_p->contenido[longitud] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*tam);

 if(p_p->contenido == NULL){
  printf("Error en la reserva de memoria de la copia de la letra\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 strcpy(p_p->contenido[longitud], letra);
 
 p_p->tamano++;

 return p_p;

}

void palabraImprime(FILE * fd, Palabra * p_p){
 int i;

 if(p_p == NULL){
  printf("Palabra a NULL a la hora de imprimir palabra\n");
  return;
 }

 fprintf(fd, "[(%d) ", p_p->tamano);
 for(i=0;i<p_p->tamano;i++){
  if(i==p_p->tamano-1){
   fprintf(fd, "%s ",p_p->contenido[i]);
  } else {
   fprintf(fd, "%s ",p_p->contenido[i]);
  }
 }
 fprintf(fd,"]\n");
 return;
}

int palabraTamano(Palabra * p_p){
 if(p_p == NULL){
  printf("Palabra a NULL a la hora de devolver el tamano de la palabra\n");
  return -1;
 }

 return p_p->tamano;
}

char * palabraQuitaInicio(Palabra * p_p){

 char* letraQuitada;

 if(p_p == NULL){
  printf("Palabra null a la hora de quitar letra\n");
  return NULL;
 }

 letraQuitada = p_p->contenido[0];
 
 p_p->contenido++;
 p_p->tamano--;
 
 return letraQuitada;
}
```

Y aquí el main del programa:

```html
#include "palabra.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
 Palabra * pal;
 int i;
 char letra [20];
 char * letrai;
 pal = palabraNueva();
 for (i=0; i < argc-1; i++)
 {
  sprintf(letra,"l_%d_%s",i,argv[1+i]);
  palabraInsertaLetra(pal,letra);
  fprintf(stdout,"pal_%d:\n",i);
  palabraImprime(stdout,pal);
  fprintf(stdout,"\n");
 }
 while ( palabraTamano(pal) > 0 )
 {
  fprintf(stdout,
  "QUITAMOS %s DE LA PALABRA QUE QUEDA ASI:\n",letrai=palabraQuitaInicio(pal));
  palabraImprime(stdout,pal);
 free(letrai);
 }
 palabraElimina(pal);
 return 0;
}
```

El error de valgrind os lo adjunto aquí abajo:

```html
==3097== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3097==     in use at exit: 208 bytes in 1 blocks
==3097==   total heap usage: 54 allocs, 53 frees, 2,996 bytes allocated
==3097== 
==3097== 208 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==3097==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3097==    by 0x400B2A: palabraInsertaLetra (palabra.c:51)
==3097==    by 0x4008EB: main (main.c:15)
==3097== 
==3097== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3097==    definitely lost: 208 bytes in 1 blocks
==3097==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3097==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3097==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3097==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3097== 
==3097== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3097== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta donde alcanzan mis matemáticas, x*0=0, luego este código:

```
pal->tamano = 0;

pal->contenido = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*pal->tamano);
```

De primeras no pinta demasiado bien. En la primera línea inicializas `pal->tamano` a 0 y después calculas la cantidad de memoria a reservar a partir de dicho valor...

De hecho si miramos la documentación al respecto vemos que pedirle a `malloc` 0 bytes no es buena idea:

> If size is zero, the return value depends on the particular library implementation (it may or may not be a null pointer), but the returned pointer shall not be dereferenced.

Así que, confirmado, esa reserva de memoria no está bien hecha. Deberías esperarte a que `pal->tamano` tuviese un valor positivo antes de llamar a `malloc`

Comment: Efectivamente era eso. Muchas gracias!